# von Neumann regular ring homomorphisms

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

Let us call a ring homomorphism $f\colon R\rightarrow S$ von Neuman regular if it has the property that for every left $S$-module $M$, the left $R$-module $f^*M$ is flat.

In particular, $\mathrm{id}_R$ is von Neumann regular if and only if every left $R$-module is flat, i. e. $R$ is von Neumann regular in the usual sense.

**Question:** Has this notion been studied? Does anyone know a reference?

The rings here are associative, unital and not necessarily commutative.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the flatness of $f^\ast M$ imply anything about the flatness of $M$? I have no mastery of flatness, especially under this transfer.

Comment: @rschwieb: It means that tensoring with $M$ preserves exactness for exact sequences which are induced up from $R$. But not any exact sequence is of this form. I don't know if anything stronger is true.

Comment: Flatness of $f^*M$ does not tell you anything about $M$ in general, as can be seen by taking $R$ to be absolutely flat (e.g., a field).